# Can't set RecordType

Tags: account, record-type, c#

I'm writing a tool to sync data from a data source into Salesforce. I'm trying to set the RecordTypeId on the Account object which I can do successfully in code, but doesn't appear in Salesforce when the sync has completed.

I am using the following code which is in a method called GetRecordTypes to retrieve all RecordTypes from Salesforce:

```
var result = service.query("SELECT Id, Name, Description, DeveloperName, IsActive FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Account'");
return result.records.Select(record => record as RecordType).ToList();
```

After this I query the results returned to get a specific RecordType:

```
RecordType recordType = GetRecordTypes().Single(recordType => recordType.DeveloperName == "Record_Type_Name");
```

Where "Record_Type_Name" is the actual record type developer name.

I can confirm that this code does return the correct record type and it contains a populated Salesforce ID.

To set the RecordTypeId in my Account object I simply do the following:

```
account.RecordTypeId = recordType.Id;
```

After debugging I can verify that the RecordTypeId property on the account object does get set correctly to the record type id returned from Salesforce. I can also verify that this object does get synced to Salesforce because the other fields within the Account object appear fine in Salesforce.

However for some reason the object in Salesforce does not have a Record Type associated with it, the field is just blank. I can manually set a record type in Salesforce but I need to be able to sync this record type through my sync tool.

Any suggestions on why this might be happening would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I just did a search through Data Management > Mass Delete Accounts with the following query:

Account Record Type > equals > Record Type Name

And all of the records that I synced appeared in the results. So it seems to actually be working correctly and yet when I look at one of the records it says that there is no record type associated. This seems very strange to me.

Comment: Does the Profile of the Running User have access to this Record Type ?

Comment: Yes it does. I've just made an edit to my post this might help

Comment: So you have the Record Type field displayed on the page layout and it shows blank?

Comment: Ah you've just helped me figure out the issue. I was getting confused between 2 fields and had the wrong one, thanks.